# Debian DHCP Client can't find DHCP Server

Tags: linux, networking, router, debian, dhcp

I have a big problem with DHCP client on Debian.
Fresh Debian 10 installation (from debian.org), DHCP Client can't find DHCP Server
Logs from syslog:

```
Listening on LPF/enp2s0/<mac>
Sending on LPF/enp2s0/<mac>
Sending on Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
No DHCPOFFERS reveived.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

But when I type manually `dhclient` I receive IP Address, but this is not solution...
IP Address should be assigned automatically
Some one know something about that?

Comment: How many NICs do you have? Are you sure that you have the right interface? What do you get from `sudo dhclient -1 enp2s0`?

Comment: Only one NIC, from `dhclient -1 enp2s0` I receive nothing. Return code `0`

Comment: @KarlWilbur also in `/etc/network/interfaces` I have two lines added: 
`allow-htoplug enp2s0 \n iface enp2s0 inet dhcp`

Comment: Everything is up-to-date with debian repository

Comment: When you manually run `dhclient`, does it receive an IP address _on the same interface_?

Comment: @user1686 yes, it receive IP address.

Comment: Also, static configurations works fine. But only DHCP have some problem to find server?! I don't know what is going on here. Manually it works fine, but on system startup it doesn't work at all.